# Versioning in Greenplum Database

Tags: greenplum

Is anyone doing versioning of Greenplum Code?

Can anyone help on this, is there any direct tool or method which can help in manage version of GP DDL/Code of database objects (Tables, Functions, Views)

Regards,

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Thanks a_horse_wth_no_name

Answer (score 1):

I've had the best success of using a cron job to commit any changes to a source control system like git or subversion on a daily basis.

```
--create a SQL file per schema
for i in $(psql -t -A -c "select nspname from pg_namespace where nspname not like 'pg_%' and nspname not like '%toolkit' and nspname not in ('information_schema', 'madlib', 'public') order by nspname;"); do 
    echo $i 
    pg_dump -s -n $i -f $i.sql
done

for i in $(ls *.sql); do
    #your code to commit the changes to source control like git
done
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, Above script will generate a sql file for each schema in database, is there any way by which i can create a sql file for each object(specially functions, i am able to pass table name in pg_dump but i didnt find anything which can generate a DDL for existing function)